# Where does Firebase store whether the user is email validated or not

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Despite spending an entire afternoon searching SO and Google I can't seem to find the answer to this question - which makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

I have setup an email authentication script, where Firebase sends the email to the user for them to verify their email address. This works fine. The link in the email seems to work, and displays a page saying you are now verified.

So far so good - BUT where does Firebase store whether the user is email validated or not?

I assumed this would be in the Authentication screen. It shows the users but no where does it show whether the user is email validated or not .... just the standard 5 columns for an Email and Password based user (Identifier, Provider, Created, Signed In and UID) but nowhere is there an option for whether that user is email validated??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not visible in the Firebase console.  But you can access this programmatically in your Flutter app in the [User](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) object with the [emailVerified](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/emailVerified.html) property.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, that's why I can't find it! Unfortunately although I am clicking on the link from with the email I have received from Firebase, when I then use the User object and check the emailVerified it's coming up false.....I'll have to keep digging!

Comment: Read the documentation I linked about the emailVerified property.  It says you have to reload the user object to see changes to that value.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! ... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The `User` class from `FirebaseAuth` contains a property called `emailVerified`, which you can read to know if the user has verified her/his email or not:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

User _user  = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password); 

if (_user.emailVerified) {
   print('The user verified the email address');
} else {
   print('The user has not verified the email address yet');
}
```